# Syntax error on Java PreparedStatement.setBytes with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, blob

I'm trying to set a BLOB mysql field with the PreparedStatement.setBytes method.
The problem is that the query ends up with a string containing the bytes to be inserted.. more or less.

So, here is the code where it's about:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = this.getStatement( "UPDATE TABLE users SET logintoken=? WHERE qrid=?" );
        stmt.setBytes( 1, token );
        stmt.setString( 2, bar.getId() );
        stmt.execute();
```

For the record, token is a byte[] always holding 20 bytes generated by SecureRandom

And here is the error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE users SET logintoken=x'6DA9D5137B059AE6BCFE7F170693A76CA6484FFB24963BF88AA' at line 1
```

As you can see, it places an x' at the beginning of the data.
Logically this breaks the query since part of the data is not contained within the string.

I assumed that the PreparedStatement.setBytes would solve the problem but it does not.
I've also tried it with a java.sql Blob object but it more or less gave the same issues.

Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: what is your token value?

Comment: I did state it above, it's a byte[] containing 20 random bytes. Generated by SecureRandom

Comment: Actually the `x` is a marker that the following data is binary data, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your `UPDATE` query closely, the `TABLE` is not necessary. it should just be like

```
UPDATE users SET logintoken=? WHERE qrid=?
```

Refer [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for more information.

Comment: Okay that was it, seems like i should stop programming at 3am because i'm overthinking and overlooking stupid stuff like this -_- thank you very much anyways :)